# Responsive Typography in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui, typography

Designs commonly have smaller headline fonts for mobile designs.

Does Material UI have a mechanism for making the typography responsive?

I see that the default theme has the font sizes defined in rems - does that mean it's a matter of just reducing the base font-size? (That doesn't seem to work, what if you want to reduce the headline fonts at different rates).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Update**

MUI v4 has responsive typography built in! Check [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes) for details.

**Old response**

[@Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2817687/luke-peavey)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52494528/6045800) is great. I wanted to add some detail to make this work in practice, because both *breakpoints* and *pxToRem* are accessible  on the theme object... making this becomes a chicken and egg problem! My approach:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core"

const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme({ ... customisations that don’t rely on theme properties... })
const { breakpoints, typography: { pxToRem } } = defaultTheme

const theme = {
  ...defaultTheme,
  overrides: {
    MuiTypography: {
      h1: {
        fontSize: "5rem",
        [breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
          fontSize: "3rem"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

export default theme
```

Answer (score 45):

None of the other answers uses the `variant` preset.

The best way to MUI v5, and use `variant`:

```
<Typography sx={{ typography: { sm: 'body1', xs: 'body2' } }} >
    Hello world!
</Typography>
```

Comment: This is the best way  Thanks

Comment: This works, thanks... Before this I was applying the breakpoints directly to `variant` parameter, it was changing the sizes but weirdly it also changed their font family back to the default roboto for some reason

Comment: Note: as it just applies the style, it doesn't actually change the variant prop, and therefore doesn't change the classname

Comment: If you were to go from h1 to h3, does it have any impact on accessibility? Does it only affect the styling vs changing the Typography component?

Answer (score 23):

As described [in the docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes) you can use the `responsiveFontSizes()` helper to make Typography font sizes in the theme responsive.

```js
import { createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

let theme = createMuiTheme();
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);
```

Comment: https://mui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes

Comment: This is the easiest out of the box. +1 for recommending this method

Comment: This needs to be the top answer.

Answer (score 18):

**Update**

The latest version of Material UI (v4) fully supports response typography. See the [official documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes) for details.

**Original Answer**

As of version 1.x, Material UI does not have a specific mechanism for handling responsive typography.

You can scale the size of all MUI `Typography` by changing the `font-size` of the `<html>` element, as you mentioned. ([docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#typography-font-size))

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  "@global": {
    html: {
      [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        fontSize: 18
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Material UI - scale font size]

**Theme overrides**

As far as i know, the only other option is to use theme overrides to define custom styles for each of the `Typography` variants.

This requires replicating some of the logic in [createTypography.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createTypography.js) (ie setting line heights to maintain vertical rhythm)

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTypography: {
      headline: {
        fontSize: pxToRem(24),
        [breakpoints.up("md")]: {
          fontSize: pxToRem(32)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[image: Edit Material UI - Responsive font size]

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Any idea why responsive typography isn't a thing in Material-UI? It seems like a no brainer.

Comment: Where's the `breakpoints` variable coming from in your 2nd snippet? I know it should come from a theme, but that's exactly the thing your creating and is not created yet at the time you're using `breakpoints`.

Comment: This is the legit answer. Thanks for sharing Luke!

Answer (score 14):

**MUI v5** adds [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) to all MUI components which supports [responsive values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221863/9449426) where you can pass an object to define the values at different breakpoints:

```
<Typography
  sx={{
    fontSize: {
      lg: 30,
      md: 20,
      sm: 15,
      xs: 10
    }
  }}
>
  This text is resized on different screen breakpoints
</Typography>
```

Similar to `Box`, `Typography` also supports [system properties](https://mui.com/components/typography/#system-props) so you can skip the `sx` prop and pass the `fontSize` property directly. The code below is the same as above, just a bit shorter to write:

```
<Typography
  fontSize={{
    lg: 30,
    md: 20,
    sm: 15,
    xs: 10
  }}
>
  This text is resized on different screen breakpoints
</Typography>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This answer is great for those small tweaks you always need to do with responsive design.  Perhaps an image should not be displayed for example in the mobile view.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 7):

## My approach with v5

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

let theme = createTheme({
  // ...
});

theme = createTheme(theme, {
  typography: {
    h1: {
      fontSize: 53,
      [theme.breakpoints.only("sm")]: {
        fontSize: 71,
      },
    },
  },
});
export default theme;
```

Answer (score 5):

This seem to be working for me v5

in App.js

...

```
import {
  createTheme,
  responsiveFontSizes,
  ThemeProvider,
} from '@mui/material/styles';

let theme = createTheme();
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router>
       .....
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

"To automate this setup, you can use the responsiveFontSizes() helper to make Typography font sizes in the theme responsive."
https://mui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes

Answer (score 1):

**MUI 5**

**Next.js 14**

`/typography.ts`

I've successfully resolved the responsive breakpoints issue by implementing Mui v5 with Typescript.

```
import { DM_Sans } from "next/font/google";
import {
  TypographyVariants as TypographyVariantsOption,
  createTheme,
} from "@mui/material/styles";

export const dm_sans = DM_Sans({
  weight: ["100", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700"],
  style: ["normal", "italic"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "swap",
});

export interface TypographyVariants extends TypographyVariantsOption {}

const theme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 900,
      lg: 1170,
      xl: 1530,
    },
  },
});

export default {
  fontFamily: `${dm_sans.style.fontFamily}`,
  htmlFontSize: 16,
  fontSize: 14,
  fontWeightLight: 300,
  fontWeightRegular: 400,
  fontWeightMedium: 500,
  fontWeightBold: 700,
  h1: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: "3.5rem",
    lineHeight: 1.167,
    letterSpacing: "-0.02em",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      fontSize: "2rem",
    },
  },
  h2: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: "2.5rem",
    lineHeight: 1.263157895,
    letterSpacing: "-0.013",
  },
  h3: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 400,
    fontSize: "1.62rem",
    lineHeight: 1.384615385,
    letterSpacing: "0em",
  },
  h4: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: "1.5rem",
    lineHeight: 1.33333,
    letterSpacing: "0.006",
  },
  h5: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: "1.25rem",
    lineHeight: 1.334,
    letterSpacing: "0em",
  },
  h6: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: "1.125rem",
    lineHeight: 1.6,
    letterSpacing: "0.0075em",
  },
  subtitle1: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 400,
    fontSize: "1.125rem",
    lineHeight: 1.75,
    letterSpacing: "0.013em",
  },
  subtitle2: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: "1rem",
    lineHeight: 1.57,
    letterSpacing: "0.013em",
  },
  body1: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 300,
    fontSize: "1.125rem",
    lineHeight: 1.555555556,
    letterSpacing: "0.013em",
  },
  body2: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 400,
    fontSize: "0.938rem",
    lineHeight: 1.4,
    letterSpacing: "0.01071em",
  },
  button: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: "0.938rem",
    lineHeight: 1.6,
    letterSpacing: "0.013em",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
  },
  caption: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 400,
    fontSize: "0.938rem",
    lineHeight: 1.6,
    letterSpacing: "0.01875em",
  },
  overline: {
    ...dm_sans.style,
    fontWeight: 400,
    fontSize: "0.688rem",
    lineHeight: 2.66,
    letterSpacing: "0.013em",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
  },
} as TypographyVariants;
```