# What is the Material UI Box component for?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Try as I might, I cannot wrap my head around the description given [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/).

> The Box component serves as a wrapper component for most of the CSS utility needs.

What are 'the' CSS utility needs?

What is the use case for this component? What problem does it solve? How do you use it?

I find the Material UI docs very limited and hard to understand. I have googled, but generally only found fairly lightweight blog posts on how to use material UI. In addition, to help understand this component, I would really appreciate any good resources (something like a better version of their own documentation if such a thing exists).

(Background, I generally understand React, JS, CSS, HTML, etc, with less strength in the latter two).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

*EDIT: This was written in the Material UI v4 days. In Material UI v5, all Material UI components allow you to define CSS styles via the `sx` prop, not just `Box`; but `Box` also accepts styling props at top-level, as well as within `sx`.*

The other answers don't really explain the motivation for using `Box`.

`Box` renders a `<div>` you can apply CSS styles to directly via React props, for the sake of convenience, since alternatives like separate CSS files, CSS-in-JS, or inline styles can be more typing and hassle to use.

For example, consider this component that uses JSS:

```
import * as React from 'react'

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
  }
}))

const Example = ({children, ...props}) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

It's much shorter to do this with `Box` by passing the props you want to it:

```
import * as React from 'react'

import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box'

const Example = ({children}) => (
  <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" alignItems="stretch" padding={1}>
    {children}
  </Box>
)
```

Notice also how `padding={1}` is a shorthand for `theme.spacing(1)`.  `Box` provides various conveniences for working with Material UI themes like this.

In larger files, it can be more of a hassle to jump back and forth from the rendered elements to the styles than if the styles are right there on the element.

Cases where you *wouldn't* want to use `Box` (Material UI v4):

- You want the enclosing component to be able to override styles by passing `classes` (`makeStyles` enables this.  `<Example classNames={{ root: 'alert' }} />` would work in the `makeStyles` example, but not the `Box` example.)
- You need to use nontrivial selectors (example JSS selectors: `$root > li > a`, `$root .third-party-class-name`)

Comment: For [material-ui v5](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/#box), Box is going to change.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, if I don't use/pass in `display="flex" padding={1}` etc., the CSS style stuff, I can just use regular ole `div`?
Aside from typing less and taking advantage of the premade stuff (`bgcolor="primary.main"`, `theme.spacing(1)` as `{1}`, or whatever else), why would anyone do it this way?! It also clutters the structure with CSS styles. Isn't inline CSS discouraged which this is basically that?!?

Comment: @reddtoric it really depends on your goals.  If you want a design team to be able to edit UI appearance without mucking around in code, then it's bad.  If you have all coders and no desire for a separate design team, then jumping back and forth between JSX and CSS is probably not worth the waste of time of mental energy compared to inline CSS.

Comment: where can I find stuff like this documented ? The [MUI documentation](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/usage/) apparently only explains how to use the components if you already know which one you want to use, not for what purpose they are meant do be used.

Comment: Actually there's this page: https://material-ui.com/system.  That was actually where I first learned about `Box`.

Comment: Ironically, Olivier Tassinari told me he doesn't recommend "creating" Box the way those examples show.

Comment: Last time I looked at v5 plans, they were talking about making all MUI components support Box styles props (but moving them inside an `sx={{ margin: 1 }}` prop)

Comment: Arrrrgh I mean https://material-ui.com/system/basics

Answer (score 14):

A `Box` is basically a `div`* on steroid. `Box` allows you to apply dynamic styles to an otherwise normal `div` very quickly like inline styles (but it's not inline styles). Besides that, it also has a first-class integration with MUI theme:

```
<Box
  sx={{
    bgcolor: 'primary.main',
    color: 'text.secondary',
    border: 4,
    borderRadius: 2,
    px: 2,
    fontWeight: 'fontWeightBold',
    zIndex: 'tooltip',
    boxShadow: 8,
  }}
>
  Box
</Box>
```

If you need to do the above with a normal `div`, you have to get the `theme` object using `useTheme` hook and create an inline styles which is not a good practice if abused everywhere:

```
<div
  style={{
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    border: '4px solid black',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius * 2,
    padding: `0 ${theme.spacing(2)}`,
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightBold,
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.tooltip,
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[8],
  }}
>
  div
</div>
```

`Box` among other components like `Typography` or `Stack` also supports [system properties](https://mui.com/components/box/#system-props) that lets you pass the style values to the top-level props, which resulted in even shorter code. Internally, the system properties are gathered and merged with the `sx` prop so they are the same thing (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69527990/9449426) answer for more detail)

```
<Box
  bgcolor="primary.main"
  color="text.secondary"
  border={4}
  borderRadius={2}
  px={2}
  fontWeight="fontWeightBold"
  zIndex="tooltip"
  boxShadow={8}
>
  Box
</Box>
```

Because `Box` leverages `sx` prop, you can also use `sx` features like adding [responsive values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221863/9449426):

```
<Box
  display={{
    xs: 'none',
    sm: 'block',
  }}
  width={{
    sm: 30,
    md: 50,
    lg: 100,
  }}
>
```

Or creating nested styles:

```
<Box
  display='flex'
  sx={{
    '& > :not(:last-child)': {
      mr: 2 // maginRight: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    ':hover': {
      bgcolor: 'green'
    }
  }}
>
```

###### When to use `Box`?

- When you want to create a styled `div` quickly when prototyping.
- When you want to create a one-off inline styles that is not really reusable anywhere else. This is convenient when you want to fix something that is a bit off in a specific part of your layout.
- When you want to add dynamic or responsive styles and make your code easier to understand at the same time because everything is defined in one place, plus the fact that `sx` syntax is highly compact.
- When you want to reference multiple MUI theme properties because many `sx` properties are theme-aware out-of-the-box.

###### When *not* to use `Box`?

- When you don't need to styles anything. Just use a normal `div` then.
- When you are using it in a highly reusable components like list item, grid item or table cell. This is because `sx` prop has the slowest performance ([2x slower than the second slowest approach](https://mui.com/system/basics/#the-sx-prop))
- When you're using other MUI components. In v5, all components from MUI has `sx` support so using `Box` as a wrapper or root component is unnecessary if you just want to style other MUI components.

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

<sup>*: By default a `Box` is a `div`, but you can override the root component of it. For example: `<Box component='span'>`</sup>

Comment: Clearest and Best answer!

Comment: This is a very good answer.

Answer (score 8):

A `Box` is just that, a box.  It's an element wrapped around its content which by itself contains no styling rules nor has any default effects on the visual output.  But it's a place to put styling rules as needed.  It doesn't offer any real functionality, just a placeholder for controlling the styles in the hierarchical markup structure.

Structurally it results in a `<div>`.

I often think of it as *semantically* similar to the JSX empty element:

```
<>
  Some elements here
</>
```

In that it's used to group things.  But it results in a `<div>` and can include some Material UI capabilities:

```
<Box className={classes.someStyling}>
  Some elements here
</Box>
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. I still do not understand. Is it fundamentally a mechanism for styling other Material-UI (or plain React) elements? Why would I wrap some other element in a <Box>?

Comment: @XavierTaylor: You may indeed not currently have a reason to wrap any of your elements.  If I have several sibling elements that I want to group together and apply a style to the grouping, I'd wrap them in a `Box`.  If I have a complex UI setup where I need nested elements to perform some CSS trickery (such as transparency effects between backgrounds and texts) then I'd use a `Box` as the parent container element, since it applies no default styling other than what I explicitly tell it.

Comment: This answer might be missleading, Box actually renders a div in the DOM whilst the `<></>" represents a React Fragment which is not rendered in the DOM, it's only used when you need to wrap multiple elements as you can only return a single element in JSX

Answer (score 7):

The Box component in Material UI it has a lot of useful stuff

The most important thing is that box element has been built in with material-ui/system functionalities by default that mean you can apply system functionalities to what you need if you use it as wrapper

**Like this example:**

```js
<Box bgcolor="primary.main" color="primary.contrastText" p={2}>
  primary.main
</Box>
```

and of course you can add css class to it as you like or not

the other good useful thing that it offer it can be warp in other components and be very helpful to apply system functionalities to it

**Like this example:**

```js
<Typography component="div" variant="body1">
  <Box color="primary.main">primary.main</Box>
</Typography>
```

Both of examples above i took them from documentation
you can find them in this link :[here](https://material-ui.com/system/palette/)

and you can find what i mean by material ui system functionalities:[here](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/)

**Note**: you can add any of material ui system functionalities to any component like docs [here](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/) but i recommend you to warp what u need with box component it make life a lot easier