# How to warp some component with rectangle box in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want something like this [Here is the example!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJwQW.png)

I try with the material UI box, but it's not rendering the box only rendering the text.

Here is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

export default function BreakpointsAsArray() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Box sx={{ width: [100, 200, 300] }}>This box has a responsive width.</Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material UI's [Box](https://mui.com/system/box/) name is quite deceptive and it doesn't mean a rectangle box will automatically be created in the rendered HTML. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451957/what-is-the-material-ui-box-component-for) is some good explanation of the box component. You still need to add css/styling to make it according to your choice. The rectangle box you see in your shared [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJwQW.png), is actually added (through some website code) to the better distinguish between the documentation text and the code snippet output. Anyhow, I [forked](https://codesandbox.io/s/breakpointsasarray-material-demo-forked-vpqyy?file=/demo.js) the codesandbox [example](https://mui.com/system/basics/#the-sx-prop) and added some custom styling to show, how the styling can be updated. You can use the `sx` prop to add any styles you needed. here is a little example.

```
sx={{
  width: "90%",
  padding: "24px 20px", // theme padding
  border: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
  borderRadius: 4
}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much..