# MUI v5: is there a performance difference between styling with system properties and sx prop?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The [Migration from v4 to v5](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#box) guide indicates:

> The `Box` system props have an optional alternative API in v5, using the `sx` prop. You can [read this section](https://mui.com/system/basics/#api-tradeoff) for the "why" behind this new API.
>
> ```
> <Box border="1px dashed grey" p={[2, 3, 4]} m={2}>
> <Box sx={{ border: "1px dashed grey", p: [2, 3, 4], m: 2 }}>
> ```

The referred section indicates:

> Having the system under one prop (`sx`) helps to differentiate props defined for the sole purpose of CSS utilities, vs. those for component business logic. It's important for the **separation of concerns**.

But when it comes to performances, do both ways fall under the benchmark item `d. Render 1,000 Box` in [Performance tradeoff](https://mui.com/system/basics/#performance-tradeoff)? Or is there any difference between using [system properties](https://mui.com/components/box/#system-props) and [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In practice, they should be the same, the system props in some components like `Box` or `Typography` will be captured and spread again in the `sx` prop ([Source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-system/src/createBox.js#L14-L15)). So it'd look like this internally:

```
const { sx: originalSx, ...otherSystemProps } = props;
// sx and system props will be merged into mergedSx
const { ..., mergedSx } = extendSxProp({ originalSx, ...otherSystemProps });

return <BoxRoot sx={mergedSx} {...} />
```

This means both approach use `sx` prop under the hood (the slowest styling approach). The one using system properties may be a tad slower because it needs to be merged with the other `sx` prop internally but I don't think it's a big issue here (Both approaches should be equally slow).

Comment: What does the [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/usage/#performance-tradeoffs) mean by c. a <StyledDiv> then?