# Box vs Stack in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I recently started using MUI for my react project. There are two layout components I am confused about i.e. Stack and Box

When should I use Stack over Box?

I know [the use case of a box.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451957/what-is-the-mui-box-component-for)

But I am not sure when to use a Stack component and what the difference between them is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Box:** The Box component serves as a wrapper component for most of the CSS utility needs.
The Box component packages all the [style functions](https://mui.com/system/basics/#all-inclusive) that are exposed in `@mui/system`.

**Stack:** Stack is like a flex container. The Stack component manages layout of immediate children along the vertical or horizontal axis with optional spacing and/or dividers between each child.

Usage of Stack:

1. Stack is concerned with one-dimensional layouts, while Grid handles two-dimensional layouts. The default direction is column which stacks children vertically.
2. By default, Stack arranges items vertically in a column. However, the direction prop can be used to position items horizontally in a row as well.
3. Use the divider prop to insert an element between each child. This works particularly well with the Divider component.
4. You can switch the direction or spacing values based on the active breakpoint.

Ref: https://mui.com/components/stack/

Answer (score 0):

**Stack:**

- The Stack component is used for arranging its children components in a vertical or horizontal stack. It's particularly useful when you want to stack components on top of each other or lay them out horizontally.
- It's similar to a flex container in CSS, allowing you to control the alignment and spacing of its children easily.

```js
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
    import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
    
    function MyComponent() {
      return (
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
          <Button variant="contained">Button 1</Button>
          <Button variant="contained">Button 2</Button>
          <Button variant="contained">Button 3</Button>
        </Stack>
      );
    }
```

**Box:**

- The Box component is a low-level utility component that can be used for a wide range of purposes, including layout, styling, and more.
- It provides a way to apply styling directly to components without having to create a wrapper div.
- It's useful for applying margins, padding, borders, and other CSS properties to components.

```js
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Box m={2} p={2} border={1}>
      <Typography variant="h6">This is a Box</Typography>
      <Typography variant="body1">It can be styled easily.</Typography>
    </Box>
  );
}
```