# Dynamically adjust ImageList columns based on screen size?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've tried using [`ImageList`](https://mui.com/components/image-list/#main-content) component instead of [`Grid`](https://mui.com/components/grid/#main-content) as I just need a grid of photos with titles and it seems to be the whole point of `ImageList`. My issue is that unlike with Grid I **cannot pass [breakpoint](https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/) props** for different screen sizes (which I find weird as this would seem logical) so that I can get **different count of columns on different screens**. What would be the best approach to adjust number of columns based on screen size?

Answer (score 11):

`ImageList` uses [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and needs the `col` prop [to set](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/b6977280a603551ff0e5412982b1464b48805cbf/packages/mui-material/src/ImageList/ImageList.js#L83-L83) the `grid-template-columns` but without any responsive API baked in. You can swap the `ImageList` with a `Box` component with the display set to `grid`, and uses the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) to declare the column template value depend on the screen size, but first let define some breakpoints:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      mobile: 0,
      bigMobile: 350,
      tablet: 650,
      desktop: 900
    }
  }
});
```

Then in the component, you can start using it like this:

```
import ImageListItem, { imageListItemClasses } from "@mui/material/ImageListItem";
```

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Box
    sx={{
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        mobile: "repeat(1, 1fr)",
        bigMobile: "repeat(2, 1fr)",
        tablet: "repeat(3, 1fr)",
        desktop: "repeat(4, 1fr)"
      }
      // standard variant from here:
      // https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3e679ac9e368aeb170d564d206d59913ceca7062/packages/mui-material/src/ImageListItem/ImageListItem.js#L42-L43
      [`& .${imageListItemClasses.root}`]: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }
    }}
  >
    {itemData.map((item) => <ImageListItem {...}/>)}
  </Box>
</ThemeProvider>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### References

- [Media queries in MUI components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221863/9449426)
- https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/#main-content

Comment: Is there a way to access default breakpoints instead of defining values ourselves here?

Comment: @Stormwaker yes, there is. See the default breakpoint values [here](https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/#default-breakpoints). I don't use it because it doesn't look nice in the live demo

Comment: @Stormwaker you don't even have to import `ThemeProvider` or `createTheme` if you only use the default values in theme just FYI.

Comment: Removing `ImageList` as parent of `ImageListItem` makes it behave a bit clunky. For example if I set `ImageListItemBar` `position` to `below` it won't appear (being hiden under next row). Of course I can set `rowGap` of this `Box` high enough so it will reveal the text again, but I'm basically starting to recreate whole `ImageList` and `ImageListItem` from the base after more of these additions. I'll stick with my solution as it allows me to keep built in features of `ImageList`.

Comment: @Stormwaker see my updated answer, I copy the relevant styles from `ImageList`

Answer (score 7):

I used the useMediaQuery hook to get the cols props for the ImageList component.

```
import { ImageList, ImageListItem, useMediaQuery } from '@mui/material';

function Gallery() {
const matches = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');
return (
    <ImageList cols={matches ? 3 : 2} variant="masonry">
      <ImageListItem>
       ...
      </ImageListItem>
    </ImageList>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO, if ok with a single breakpoint. Works well and is a simple solution. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

I spotted a similar problem. The `ImageList` renders a `<ul>` tag in DOM. Hence I created my own `ImageList` styled `<ul>` component which works fine with `ImageListItem`. Here as per the `gridTemplateColumns` attribute for screens with display size `sm` will show 2 images, display size `md` will show 4 images
and display size `lg` will show 5 images.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ImageListItem from '@mui/material/ImageListItem';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const ImageGalleryList = styled('ul')(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'grid',
    padding: 0,
    margin: theme.spacing(0, 4),
    gap: 8,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(2, 1fr)'
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(4, 1fr)'
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(5, 1fr)'
    },
}));

export default function ImageGallery({imageData}) {
    return (
        <ImageGalleryList>
            {itemData.map((item) => (
                <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
                    // Replace this with your ImageListItem
                </ImageListItem>
            ))}
        </ImageGalleryList>
    );
}
```

Comment: Seems good. Although the best way to go about it is probably just opening an issue on `material-ui` github repo and modifying the `ImageList` component to take breakpoints as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using ImageList I used "Image masonry" seems to work.
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-masonry/#main-content

```
<Masonry columns={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3, lg: 4, xl: 5 }} spacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2 }}>
```

Image masonry
This example demonstrates the use of Masonry for images. Masonry orders its children by row. If you'd like to order images by column, check out ImageList.

Comment: How does one import Masonry? I tried `import Masonry from '@mui/lab/Masonry';` and received `export 'default' (imported as 'Masonry') was not found in '@mui/lab/Masonry' (module has no exports)`

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer I had to add https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/lab

Answer (score 2):

This solution I came up with works, but seems like a lot of lines for something that Grid handles out of the box. Doesn't ImageList have some built in responsive design implementation?

```
export function Example(props) {
    // not sure if there is a way to get something like this dictionary from React?
    const breakpoints = {
        xs: 0,
        sm: 600,
        md: 960,
        lg: 1280,
        xl: 1920
    }

    const getColumns = (width) => {
        if (width < breakpoints.sm) {
            return 2
        } else if (width < breakpoints.md) {
            return 3
        } else if (width < breakpoints.lg) {
            return 6
        } else if (width < breakpoints.xl) {
            return 7
        } else {
            return 8
        }
    }

    const [columns, setColumns] = useState(getColumns(window.innerWidth))
    const updateDimensions = () => {
        setColumns(getColumns(window.innerWidth))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
    }, []);

    return (
        <ImageList cols={columns}>
          {/* list items ... */}
        </ImageList>
    )
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me too. Did you ever find out whether MUI has a simpler solution, akin to what Grid does out of the box?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer In the end I felt like ImageList is not very thought-out and created layout to suit my needs using Grid component.

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet utilizes Material-UI's `ImageList` and `ImageListItem` components to create a responsive grid of images with customizable gaps and column widths.

```
<ImageList
  gap={12}
  sx={{
    gridTemplateColumns:
      'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr))!important',
  }}
>
  <ImageListItem>{your_item_comes_here}<ImageListItem>
</ImageList>
```

`<ImageList>`: This tag is the beginning of the `ImageList` component provided by Material-UI, which is a container for `ImageListItem` components.

`gap={12}`: This attribute sets the gap between the items in the image list to 12 pixels.

`sx={{...}}`: The `sx` attribute is a Material-UI specific attribute that allows you to apply custom CSS styles to the component. It is a shorthand syntax for writing inline styles.

`gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr))!important'`: This style rule is a CSS Grid Layout property that defines the columns for the component.

`repeat(auto-fill, minmax(280px, 1fr))` tells the browser to create as many columns as it can fit within the container while maintaining a minimum width of 280 pixels and magximum width of 1fr for each column. The `!important` declaration gives this rule higher specificity, ensuring it takes precedence over any other conflicting CSS rules.

`<ImageListItem>{your_item_comes_here}<ImageListItem>`: This pair of tags represents the `ImageListItem` component provided by Material-UI. You should replace `{your_item_comes_here}` with the actual content (e.g., an image) you want to display within the list item.

`</ImageList>`: This tag is the ending tag for the `ImageList` component.

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the note @SuperKai-KazuyaIto, I added the explanation above.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy

> useBreakPoint.Js

```
import { useMediaQuery, useTheme } from '@mui/material';

const useBreakpoint = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const breakpoints = theme.breakpoints.keys;
  const matchingBreakpoint = breakpoints.filter((key) => useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only(key)));
  
  return matchingBreakpoint;
};

export default useBreakpoint;
```

> Home.js

```
export default function Home() {
  const breakpoint = useBreakpoint();
  const cols = {
    xs: 2,
    sm: 3,
    md: 4,
    lg: 6,
    xl: 8,
  }[breakpoint];

    return (
        <ImageList cols={cols}>
            {itemData.map((item) => (
                <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
                    // Replace this with your ImageListItem
                </ImageListItem>
            ))}
        </ImageList>
    );
}
```

Comment: Very elegant and flexible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by overriding `column-count` property on ImageList (root component)

So, you can add breakpoints using sx props

```
<ImageList
  sx={{
    columnCount: {
      xs: '1 !important',
      sm: '2 !important',
      md: '3 !important',
      lg: '4 !important',
      xl: '5 !important',
    },
  }}
>
  {/* list items ... */}
</ImageList>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me at all. Had no effect.

Comment: Also didn't work for me.