# Responsive imageList in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsive

I want to decrease the amount of `imageList` columns depending on the display width (a.k.a. media query) but it doesn't work properly.
For example:

```js
<ImageList variant="masonry" cols={{ xl: 3, md: 2, sm: 1 }} gap={18}>
  {images.map((image) => (
    <ImageListItem key={image.id}>
      <img
        src={image.urls.regular}
        srcSet={image.urls.regular}
        alt={image.alt_description}
        loading="lazy"
      />
    </ImageListItem>
  ))}
</ImageList>
```

If I do this, I only get 1 column, and if I try `cols={3}`, I get 3 columns. Any tips?

Comment: Did you see: [Dynamically adjust ImageList columns based on screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383051/dynamically-adjust-imagelist-columns-based-on-screen-size?noredirect=1&lq=1) ?

Comment: Haven`t seen until yesterday.  The solution seems a bit weird to me but at least I can work with it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 8):

You can change the number of columns dynamically, depending on theme media queries. Use something like this:

```js
const matchDownMd = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));
```

So you can use it later like this:

```
cols={matchDownMd ? 1 : 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is so annoying not being able to do a responsive grid through this " cols={{ xl: 3, md: 2, sm: 1 }} " code.
Here is another approach. I read the class name of Mui " ImageList " element. it is " MuiImageList-root "

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .MuiImageList-root {
    column-count: 3 !important;
  }
}
```

This code turns my "ImageList" grid into a responsive design. I hope there will be another answer about inline CSS code.

Answer (score -3):

The answer in this other thread solved the problem for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71804564/16238799
Quoting that answer here for quick reference:

```
<ImageList
  sx={{
    columnCount: {
      xs: '1 !important',
      sm: '2 !important',
      md: '3 !important',
      lg: '4 !important',
      xl: '5 !important',
    },
  }}
>
  {/* list items ... */}
</ImageList>
```