# Use breakpoints in Material-UI Container

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use **Container** and it needs to be different size for mobile and for desktop.

How can I have the **Container** `maxWidth` different size based on **Breakpoints** like this:

```
<Container maxWidth={{xs:"lg", lg:"md"}}>
```

instead of using the **`useStyle`** and adding a `className`.

Comment: You can try `useMediaQuery` https://mui.com/components/use-media-query/

Answer (score 3):

I  found most of answer related to functional component, but if you are using class component we can directly use like this.  I like to use 'vh' and 'vw' as  this unit  is direclty adjustable to viewport.

```
                     <Container
                            sx={{
                                width: {
                                    lg: '35vw',
                                    md: '50vw',
                                    xs: '70vw'
                                  }
                              
                            }}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the `sx` prop which supports [responsive values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221863/9449426). The breakpoint values can be accessed in `theme.breakpoints.values` object. See the [default theme](https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/#main-content) here to know more.

```
const theme = useTheme();
```

```
<Container
  sx={{
    bgcolor: "wheat",
    maxWidth: {
      lg: theme.breakpoints.values["md"],
      md: 80,
      xs: 20
    }
  }}
>
  <Box sx={{ bgcolor: "#cfe8fc", height: "100vh", width: "100%" }} />
</Container>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]